# Is it possible to maintain a parameter table in loadrunner?

Tags: javascript, parameters, loadrunner

Lets assume I've defined a key/value pair in loadrunner parameters 
section called mytable.dat (Parameter type: Table)

Does loadrunner have a built in function to update this table?
Can I access a value according to key?

In other words, lets say this table consists of user name which will be the key
and email address as value - I would like to ask get the address of a certain user and update his email so when I run the test again tomorrow, loadrunner will load an updated version of mytable.dat

I would like to avoid programming it in c, if there is no built in way to do it in loadrunner than I would much prefer to handle it using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your core problem with dynamic update.  The table you update on disk is not the table which is used by your virtual users.  At the beginning of the test the parameter table is loaded into RAM to lessen disk access.   So, any writes you make to the table are only going to be available at the next test execution.

The next problem is not trivial and is the core reason that database management solutions exist, how will you manage the read/write access for tens/hundreds/thousands of users to a given file for updates?  This is a difficult programming challenge.  Get it wrong and you will lock your file system on your load generators...even worse if the file is on a common file server where you now have access across a network involved.   This will result in slowed virtual users as everyone waits for exclusive lock to update the table.

Using a queue is really the best option to feed your virtual users where you have one business process which needs to update the data table which is used by a second business process.  Noted in this same thread is VTS, which ships as a part of LoadRunner to address this very issue.   My preference is RabbitMQ, as it has a build in HTTP interface to push and pop values from the queues.  You could also leverage any of the serverless computing queues from Amazon, Cloud Azure, IBM Cloud, Rackspace, etc... for this type of event.

Some people want to use a database server for this feed.  I recommend against this option as when implemented the form most often in place is to use the same database for feeding data as the application under test.  This places load on the AUT which is not present in production. This load is also never optimized on the queries to return the one row of data needed, so the load is disproportionate to the number of users then directly connected to the database which doesn't happen in prod.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am familiar with RabbitMQ so I am definitely going to test this option and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

In LoadRunner there are 3 types of parameters:

1) Static - The parameters you define using the parameters dialog in VuGen (e.g. the Table type parameter you are talking about). These parameters are read only and can be accessed using the curly brackets notation:

```
lr_message(lr_eval_string("{NewParam}"));
```

2) Dynamic - Parameters you define using the code within your script and can be read and written in code (and accessed via curly brackets):

```
lr_save_string("aaaa","bbb");
lr_message(lr_eval_string("{bbb}"));
```

3) VTS - This is basically a small database which you can access from any vUser running the script and you have full control over what is going on there with appropriate API (please read the documentation on VTS)

Some other notes:
"Table" parameter is a way to access multiple values with one parameter, make sure this is the parameter type you really need.

Some protocols support JavaScript as the scripting language. To switch the language to JavaScript go to Record -> Recording Options, in the dialog General -> Script and change the language to JavaScript. Then regenerate the script (or record an empty script) and it will be regenerated in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the only way to load an object from disk and maintain it with full and easy control would be to use JS. I was looking for an out of the box solution within vugen but apparently it doesn't exist.

Comment: If you need further assistance, feel free to contact us via the LR official support forum or the send feedback link in VuGen Help menu